# LTC6991 : unexpected ouput signal

Tags: timer

I'm trying to make a 50% oscillator with a Tout=10ms period. Instead, I get a 5.7ms period signal, and an off pulse (low level) of 150µs !

I chose POL=0 and RESET is grounded. From table 1 of the datasheet, I pick the 2nd line : DIVCODE=1, NDIV=8, R1=1Meg, R2=100K. Vdd=3.3V, Vdiv=0.29V => Vdiv/Vdd=0.088 (OK, should be 0.091). Then, I calculate Rreset = 50k/1.024ms*Tout/NDIV=61K, I pick 68K.

What's wrong ?

[image]

Comment: Show your circuit including the power supply and decoupled capacitors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although for both schematics the 1 MΩ resistor is between the right middle pin and right lower pin, you have swapped the pins in your schematic.
In your schematic resistor R7 is connected between **OUT (pin 6)** and DIV (pin 4) instead of V+ (pin 5) and DIV.

[image]